# Markdown List Parsing

Tags: list, latex, markdown

I am writing a markdown document with a lot of short lists with headings

```
This is a sentence describing a list:

- Hello
- World
```

This renders fine, but the space between the heading sentence and list makes the markdown disorganized, especially since my document has so many short lists.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
This is a sentence describing a list:
- Hello
- World
```

so there is no space between the heading and list in markdown file.  Unfortunately, markdown renders that as one big sentence ("This is a sentence describing a list: -hello -world") and not as a list.  Is there a way to force a break at the end of the line to make markdown recognize the dashes as a list?  A solution of this format

```
This is a sentence describing a list:[something like \newline]
- Hello
- World
```

would be perfect.  I would like to do this in straight markdown, but for right now I have additional flexibility of Latex commands since I am embedding markdown within a Latex document (this package: https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf)

Comment: I strongly disagree that the blank line "makes the markdown disorganized". Whitespace almost always aids readability. But that's not objective, and some Markdown implementations do (or can do) exactly what you want. What is the specific renderer that you are targeting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fake bullet lists to achieve this. You can build them up using non-breaking spaces and a ⦁ (Z NOTATION SPOT) character.

```
This is a sentence describing a list:[space][space]
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⦁&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello[space][space]
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⦁&nbsp;&nbsp;World
```

## Result:

This is a sentence describing a list:
   ⦁  Hello
   ⦁  World

## For comparison, here's a real bullet list:

This is a sentence describing a list:

- Hello
- World